# Azure function not running parallel

Tags: .net, azure, parallel-processing, azure-functions

I have created an azure function in python.
I am calling it via C# and I am expected to send out about 1000 request simultaneously. What I need it for this function is to process those request in parallel and not one after the other, but I cant make it happen.

Here is my test code that sends 10 requests in parallel.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> symbols = new List<string> { "MSFT", "AAPL", "NFLX", "JNJ", "INTC", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "TSLA", "TSM" };           
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        Parallel.ForEach(symbols, (symbol) =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Getting - " + symbol);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MY FUNCTION URL");
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            Trace.WriteLine("Finished - " + symbol);
        });
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

I can see that the requests are sent all together. but the processing is one after the other.
here is my host.json file :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1
    },
    "http": {
    "routePrefix": "api",
    "maxOutstandingRequests": 200,
    "maxConcurrentRequests": 1
    }
```

}
}

As far as I understood setting "maxConcurrentRequests" to 1 enforces the function app to scale out and create multiple instances. I have tried setting this value to 10 and 100 and it did nothing.

I have also tried adding the following configuration values to the function app:

FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT = 10.

PYTHON_THREADPOOL_THREAD_COUNT = 32.

that did not make any difference as well.

I can see in the azure analytics that the functions are processed one after the other according to their timestamps. and also the accumulated time is ~ 10 * a single run.

I am pretty sure its a configuration issue, what have I missed?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: Wild guess but try setting `extensions.queues.batchSize` to 10?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary  extensions.queues.batchSize is for storage queue settings and tells the functions to retrieve that many messages from the queue at one go.   It has no impact to http request processing. See the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings

Answer (score 0):

Have look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output#hostjson-settings) which says

> The maximum number of HTTP functions that are executed in parallel.
> This value allows you to control concurrency, which can help manage
> resource utilization. For example, you might have an HTTP function
> that uses a large number of system resources (memory/cpu/sockets) such
> that it causes issues when concurrency is too high. Or you might have
> a function that makes outbound requests to a third-party service, and
> those calls need to be rate limited. In these cases, applying a
> throttle here can help.
> *The default for a Consumption plan is 100. The default for a Dedicated plan is unbounded (-1).

Setting it to 1, is basically telling it NOT to process the requests in parallel. If you set it to 100, it will attempt to process 100 at a time. If the memory or CPU required is more and there are still more requests in queue, functions will start automatically scaling up (assuming you are on consumption plan).

Comment: I have changed it to 10 and 100 and it did not make any difference

Comment: What code is your function using? If it is python then you can try changing the worker process count to 10 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_process_count and the thread pool count to 32 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#python_threadpool_thread_count. If it still doesn't work, you should edit the question with the code of your function.

Comment: I have tried those two settings, they did not change anything. I cannot share my function code as its sensitive IP. its basically many calculation using pandas. It takes about 4-8 seconds.

Comment: What is the size of the data being processed? You are limited to the RAM of the function instance. If you are using app service with no scale up rules setup and if you are hitting the RAM limits, your function will process 1 request at a time. If you are using consumption plan you are limited to 1.5GB and it may not get enough time to scale up with just 10 requests. Could you check your live application insights to see what is the CPU and memory consumption when the 10 requests are received and let us know what service plan you are using?

Comment: I am using the consumption plan. on live metrics it shows that the committed size is ~800MB and CPU is at 2%, even with nothing running, once I send the 10 requests nothing really changes in both metrics.